# Need to run 2 110 AC from a 220 4 wire drop line on a dual 30 amp breaker

Tags: 120-240v

I have a $0 budget I need to run 2 110 AC units on 1 240 10g 4 wire supply line on a dual 30 amp breaker. Is this possible

Comment: Who cares about A/C in October?  Anyway no, not on $0 budget. $12 for a breaker puts you in the game though.

Comment: possible-Yes, on a $0 budget- No, but if you already have the hardware- go ahed and connect it. 240 is is already two phases. So you need each one with neutral for 120 V going over a single 30 A breaker

Comment: People who live in the Southern Hemisphere, @Harper-ReinstateMonica! ;)

Comment: what are the specs on the AC units for current draw?

Comment: Given that you can't actually do it for no money, the better solution is to put a sub-panel at the end of the wire.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't going to happen on a $0 budget. At a minimum you will need some outlets, some wiring supplies possibly including a new junction box, and a new breaker.

If you plan to install two 15A or two 20A outlets on the far end of the supply, you can perhaps do this if you switch to an appropriately sized dual-pole breaker. [Here is an extensive blog post about shared neutrals.](https://esgrounding.com/blog/how-many-hot-wires-can-a-single-neutral-support-assuming-they-are-the-same-gauge-wire) The tl;dr version of it is that shared neutrals are allowed in limited circumstances, but discouraged.